# Implement C++ sort function, according to the input items to sort

Tags: c++

I create an array of a struct:

```
struct student {
    char name[20];
    int num1;
    int num2;
} temp[20] = {0};
```

Its internal data is like this:

```
temp[0]={'a',1,11};
temp[1]={'b',2,12};
temp[2]={'c',3,13};
temp[3]={'d',4,14};
temp[4]={'e',5,15};
...
```

I know that I can define a compare function to tell the `sort()` function the role of sorting, for example:

```
bool cmp (student a,student b){
    return a.num1 > b.num1;
}

sort(temp, temp+20, cmp);
```

My question is: How could I sort the array using this `sort()` function based on the items I read in with `scanf()`?

Specifically, if I `scanf()` the `num1` field, the sort function sorts the data based on `num1`.

If I `scanf()` the `num2` field, the sort function sorts the data based on `num2`.

The role of sorting follows my `scanf()` item.

So, how can I realize this?

Comment: Ignoring the main request for code, you've got another issue: `'a'` isn't a string, that's a character literal. You need double quotes `"a"` to make a string.

Comment: Do not tag this as `C` when the code is `C++`.

Comment: You don't seem to have made a significant attempt at solving your problem, or at least aren't showing it. Please read [ask].

Comment: If you want to sort by different fields simply create separate comparator functions for each field. Note that `cmp` should be changed to take `a` and `b` by reference

Answer (score 0):

You can have both the reading and the sorting depend on a pointer-to-member.

So instead of

```
void read_num1(student & s) {
    std::scanf("%d", std::addressof(s.num1));
}

void compare_num1(student lhs, student rhs) {
    return lhs.num1 < rhs.num1;
}

int main() {
    student students[20];
    for (student & s : students) {
        read_num1(s);
    }

    std::sort(std::begin(students), std::end(students), compare_num1);
}
```

You have functions that have an extra parameter, and close over that where necessary

```
using member_t = int (student::*);

void read(student & s, member_t member) {
    std::scanf("%d", std::addressof(s.*member));
}

void compare(student lhs, student rhs, member_t member) {
    return (lhs.*member) < (rhs.*member);
}

int main() {
    member_t member = /* some condition */ true ? &student::num1 : &student::num2;

    student students[20];
    for (student & s : students) {
        read(s, member);
    }

    std::sort(std::begin(students), std::end(students), [member](student lhs, student rhs) { return compare(lhs, rhs, member); });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the [ranges interface](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/sort) for sort in the STL. Change your array to use `std::array` or better `std::vector` and then you can do sorting as simple as this:

```
ranges::sort(s, [](int a, int b) { return a > b; });
print("Sort using a lambda expression", s);

Particle particles[] {
    {"Electron", 0.511}, {"Muon", 105.66}, {"Tau", 1776.86},
    {"Positron", 0.511}, {"Proton", 938.27}, {"Neutron", 939.57},
};
ranges::sort(particles, {}, &Particle::name);
print("\nSort by name using a projection", particles, '\n');
ranges::sort(particles, {}, &Particle::mass);
print("Sort by mass using a projection", particles, '\n');
```

And if you want to sort by multiple fields, e.g last_name, first_name, you can use a `std::tuple` with references into your struct as projection. `std::tuple` has lexicographical comparison so you really just have to give the order of fields and the rest happens by magic.